# Grails 3.017 not showing the fields of the domain class fields in localhost 8080

Tags: groovy, grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I am new to Grails . I am using Grails 3.0.17 in my project .
I have created a dummy project named A
I have created a dummy class B in my domain as below:-

```
class B {
    String name
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**I have auto generated the controller for these**

**I have auto generated the views for this domain**
Controller looks like this:-

```
package a

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class BController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond B.list(params), model:[bCount: B.count()]
    }

    def show(B b) {
        respond b
    }

    def create() {
        respond new B(params)
    }

    @Transactional
    def save(B b) {
        if (b == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (b.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond b.errors, view:'create'
            return
        }

        b.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'b.label', default: 'B'), b.id])
                redirect b
            }
            '*' { respond b, [status: CREATED] }
        }
    }

    def edit(B b) {
        respond b
    }

    @Transactional
    def update(B b) {
        if (b == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (b.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond b.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }

        b.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'b.label', default: 'B'), b.id])
                redirect b
            }
            '*'{ respond b, [status: OK] }
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    def delete(B b) {

        if (b == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return
        }

        b.delete flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'b.label', default: 'B'), b.id])
                redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
        }
    }

    protected void notFound() {
        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'b.label', default: 'B'), params.id])
                redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
        }
    }
}
```

But when i run localhost:8080 i am not able to see the fields name ,
Here is how it looks :-
[image]

[image]

As you can see i am not able to see the name fields there in create page nor in index page.

I have tried using dynamic scaffolding too it dosent work .

Can u please help me get the fields so that i can perform basic crud operation here?

Here are my gsp files:-
**Create.gsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'b.label', default: 'B')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#create-b" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
                <li><g:link class="list" action="index"><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="create-b" class="content scaffold-create" role="main">
            <h1><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <g:hasErrors bean="${this.b}">
            <ul class="errors" role="alert">
                <g:eachError bean="${this.b}" var="error">
                <li <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}"/></li>
                </g:eachError>
            </ul>
            </g:hasErrors>
            <g:form action="save">
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <f:all bean="b"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
                </fieldset>
            </g:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit.gsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'b.label', default: 'B')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.edit.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#edit-b" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
                <li><g:link class="list" action="index"><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
                <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="edit-b" class="content scaffold-edit" role="main">
            <h1><g:message code="default.edit.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <g:hasErrors bean="${this.b}">
            <ul class="errors" role="alert">
                <g:eachError bean="${this.b}" var="error">
                <li <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}"/></li>
                </g:eachError>
            </ul>
            </g:hasErrors>
            <g:form resource="${this.b}" method="PUT">
                <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${this.b?.version}" />
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <f:all bean="b"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <input class="save" type="submit" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" />
                </fieldset>
            </g:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Index.gsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'b.label', default: 'B')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#list-b" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
                <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="list-b" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
            <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
                <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <f:table collection="${bList}" />

            <div class="pagination">
                <g:paginate total="${bCount ?: 0}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Show.gsp:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'b.label', default: 'B')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#show-b" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
                <li><g:link class="list" action="index"><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
                <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="show-b" class="content scaffold-show" role="main">
            <h1><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <f:display bean="b" />
            <g:form resource="${this.b}" method="DELETE">
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <g:link class="edit" action="edit" resource="${this.b}"><g:message code="default.button.edit.label" default="Edit" /></g:link>
                    <input class="delete" type="submit" value="${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" />
                </fieldset>
            </g:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason you're using a version of grails from Apr 28, 2016?

Comment: It was the prescribed version for us

Comment: Might help if you showed your gsps and resulting page source.

Comment: @Daniel I have added it

Comment: I don't have grails 3 documentation readily available, but I don't believe that the convention for `respond` includes a variable named `this`.  Switch to `b` instead, and see if that works.  For your index/list page, once you have objects in the list I believe your `bList` convention is already correct.